# TSQL - Stored Procedure - Execute as Owner - Openquery

Tags: t-sql, stored-procedures, openquery

I'm using SQL Server 2008.

There is a Procedure ...

```
CREATE PROCEDURE xxx WITH EXECUTE AS OWNER
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

   TRUNCATE TABLE ttt;

   INSERT INTO ttt
      (
         field
      )
       SELECT
         order_number
      FROM
         OPENQUERY([sss], 'SELECT ...') 
END
```

... the Owner User can execute the procedure without any issue.

My Expectation was, if I grant execution access to some other User the other user should also be able to run this procedure.

But using the other Account a error is received: '`Access to the remote server is denied because no login-mapping exists.`'

Actually I try to avoid giving the 'other User' full access to the linked Server.

Comment: *"I'm using SQL Server 2008."* SQL Server 2008 has been out of support for over a year now, you should really be looking at upgrade paths now

Comment: Yes, it is sad but I unfortunately can't change it. I'll forward you recommendation to higher levels.

Comment: `EXECUTE AS OWNER` will impersonate the object owner, i.e. a particular user in that database, but the remote server must be mapped to a specific server login, if the executing user's login can't access the remote server, they won't be able to query it, even if they execute as a different user on the calling database. You'd need to configure the linked server to use a specified login, or impersonate a login, rather than a user.

Answer (score 1):

> User must be mapped to db_owner group